# Can anyone explain the internal working of list comprehension for cases where there's if-else and the other where there's only if condition?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following 3 expressions:

`['-'+i+'-' if int(i)%2==0 else i for i in str(num).strip('-')]` ~~~~(1)

`[i if i in ar and ar[i]>4 for i in s]` ~~~~~(2), (where `ar` is a map)

`[i if i in ar and ar[i]>4 else continue for i in s]` ~~~~~~(3)

Only expression (1) works. The rest two don't. However, if I re-write the expression (2) as follows:

`[i for i in s if i in ar and ar[i]>4]`, it works fine.

I am interested in understanding the internal working of this.

Comment: What do you mean by “works” - please edit the result of (2 and (3) into your question and provide the data these are operating `num`, `ar`, `s` etc. on so others can reproduce what you are seeing. If there are Python errors plpease edit the _full_ error message into your question _as text_.

Comment: The [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) doc has useful examples.

Comment: The recipe for a comprehension is an expression followed by a `for` clause followed by an `if`. `'-'+i+'-' if int(i)%2==0 else i` is an expression, `i if i in ar and ar[i]>4` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['-'+i+'-' if int(i)%2==0 else i for i in str(num).strip('-')]` works because of else. in this case it uses conditional expression[0], rather the normal syntax for comprehension lists. "A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses"[1]

The normal form is `[expression_statement forloop if_filter]`, right?
So instead of (2) you should have

```
[i for i in s if i in ar and ar[i]>4]
```

which it is equivalent with

```
alist = []
for i in s:
    if i in ar and ar[i]>4]:
        alist.append(i)
```

[0] https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions